# How to calculate values for preceeding quarter based on filter selection

Tags: tableau-api

I have a column named 'time period' which contains just year and quarter values, like 2023 q1, 2022 q4, etc. no date values. I want to create a dynamic calculated field where if I select 2023 Q1 in the filters, I can calculate difference with previous quarter i.e. 2022 Q4 in tableau.

For example, I have sales=10 in 2023 Q1 and sales=9 in 2022 q4, I want to create a calculated field where I am seeing 1 as the difference when 2023 Q1 is selected in filter.

Note: the year quarter column is in datatype string and sales is in float.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.